# Why can't Spring Boot inject attribute values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inject

I need to inject the FTP configuration.
But one of the attributes cannot be injected successfully.
Everything else can inject success.

My `application.yml` is as follows:

```
ftp:
    connect:
        local-dir: /temp/   # This attribute injection failed
        ip-host: xxx.xxx.xx.x
        port: 21
        username: xxx
        password: xxxx
        work-path: /
```

Here's my receiving class :

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("ftp.connect")
public class FtpConfig {
    /**
     * ftp server ip
     */
    private String ipHost;
    /**
     * ftp server opens the port
     */
    private Integer port;
    /**
     * ftp server login username
     */
    private String username;
    /**
     * ftp server password
     */
    private String password;
    /**
     * ftp default working path
     */
    private String workPath;
    /**
     * local store directory
     */
    private String localDir;
}
```

It working, but I can't get the value of localDir, which is `null`.

---

I executed the wrong main method :(

Comment: "It working, but I can't get the value of localDir, which is null." Then it's not working. Maybe rename local-dir to localDir or add an alias to localDir of local-dir?

Comment: @mre Don't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? I wouldn't be surprised if ipHost or workPath isn't populated either.

Comment: Rename `local-dir` to `localDir`.  All other attributes were successfully injected.

Comment: I'm not sure how it was able to resolve that, but maybe you need to escape the backslashes in the path (although workPath is magically working)?

Comment: Don't use `@Component` on an `@ConfigurationProperties`; they mean different things. Most likely, you also *aren't* using `@EnableConfigurationProperties` (which would usually result in an error). Try switching to `@ECP` (on a configuration class) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @mre Still not woking, I changed the value of `local-dir` to `ftplocalstorepath`

Comment: Michael, why don't you share so that this post may become useful to someone in  the future?

Comment: This is a good one with less config code, but you can also try `@Value` annotation to inject properties

Comment: @ScaryWombat , Because it's not a configuration issue, it's a matter of how I run it, Ididn't run `SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args)`.